# gawk - fatal division by zero attempted

Tags: awk, scripting

So i wrote a simple gawk script called script.awk that looks like the below

```
  
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f

# Sorts by ascending order
# ROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
BEGIN{
    FS=","
    drunkCases=0
    totalCases=0
    friSatAccident=0
    totalCasesMI=0
    drunkCasesMI=0
    darkCasesMI=0
}
#Count total cases so we can calculate proportions
NR>1{totalCases+=1}

#Count drunk driving cases
NR>1 && $52>=1{drunkCases+=1}

#Count accidents on Friday or Saturday
NR>1 && ($15 == 6 || $15 == 7) {friSatAccident+=1}

#Count total Accident cases in michigan
NR>1 && $1 == 26 {totalMI+=1}

#Count total Drunk drivers in michigan accidents
NR>1 && $1 == 26 && $52 >= 1 {drunkCasesMI+=1} 

# Counts accidents in michigan that occured in the dark
NR>1 && $1 == 26 && ($36 == 2 || $36 == 3 || $36 == 6) {darkCasesMI+=1}

#array that holds number of people for each state code in a key where the key is the state code. 
NR>1{stateAccCount[$1]+=$9}
END{
    print "DD Proportion: " drunkCases/totalCases
    print "Friday/Saturday Proportion: " friSatAccident/totalCases
    print "MI DD Proportion: " drunkCasesMI/totalCasesMI
    print "MI Dark Proportion: " darkCasesMI/totalCasesMI
    print "State Code,# People"
    for (key in stateAccCount){
        print key","stateAccCount[key]
    }
}
```

However i get an error when trying to run it that says

```
Your code produced an error when running
gawk: script_cnv.awk:37: (FILENAME=- FNR=10) fatal: division by zero attempted

Stdout is
DD Proportion: 0.666667
Friday/Saturday Proportion: 0.444444
```

I dont see what im doing wrong. I tried to read through my script again to make sure there were no typos and didnt find anything. Im confused on why its trying to divide by zero, the values should not be zero. what am i doing wrong

Comment: "The values should not be zero." But one of them is. You get the first two results, but it fails before "MI DD Proportion" gets printed. Therefore, that is line 37 of the awk script, and totalCasesMI is zero. Print all the divisors by themselves as debug at the top of the END block. Then, figure why the Drunk cases does not increment the divisor. Either the data has no instances, or the tests are wrong (probably the column numbers). You only have ten data records -- post them.

Comment: `totalMI` should be `totalCasesMI`. Also, do what [@thanasisp suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617364/133219).

Comment: why would you think that the error is caused by a typo? ... there is nothing to be confused about ... the variable value is zero ... if you believe that it should be non-zero, then trace the program flow backward to the point where the non-zero value is supposedly assigned and confirm by inspecting the variable value

Answer (score 4):

There is a variable never assigned a value other than zero, and at the `END` you do divisions where this variable is the divisor, that is the cause of the fatal error "division by zero attempted".

```
> grep -n totalCasesMI script.awk
10:    totalCasesMI=0
37:    print "MI DD Proportion: " drunkCasesMI/totalCasesMI
38:    print "MI Dark Proportion: " darkCasesMI/totalCasesMI
```

Note that the same would happen if line 10 was missing, as the `awk` variables are evaluated as empty strings or zero if they haven't been initialized.

A good workaround for this case, useful to exist even after you have modified your code to actually assign a value to this variable, is to test first the divisor against zero. A conditional statement would be good, something like this:

```
(totalCasesMI==0 ? "N/A" : drunkCasesMI/totalCasesMI)
```